Unable to access rowy subtable data in flutter
I have to implement rowy data in my flutter application, but I stuck in access sub table data.Like  Main collection name MF_Live_NFO_Fund_Details and inside I have subtables like fundDetails. I tried to access this but its return 'permission denied' but permission was given to my main collect
final response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('MF_Live_NFO_Fund_Details')
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs);
  debugPrint(
         'mf home page ~ response ~ ${await response[0].reference.collection('fundDetails').get()}');

I'm trying to read subtable data , but its return permission denied already permission by maincollection.

check your read, write rules in firebase console . make those ops allowed

You need to update your Firebase security rules to allow read access to the subcollection as well.
